# File not Found issue when debugging html file Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to add a html file to a project of mine (That I keep saved in OneDrive incase thats important) and when I tried debugging it on Edge it I kept on getting "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". The name of the file in the URL (following the directory stuff) was [object%20HTMLSelectElement] instead of the actual HTML file name. For a split second you can see the actual webpage along with the CSS I implemented using a stylesheet but it disappears and shows the file not found error.

I went to ChatGPT (genius I know) to see if it could help and it suggested that I moved the html file from 1 folder to another. I did that and it worked however I needed access to CSS and JS files that were inside the first folder. When I moved the file back to the original folder the name of the file in the URL changed to "null".

I was also told to add an action="" to my form element (since thats what my HTML file has) and it had no change.

What I get:
file:///C:/Users/[my username]/OneDrive/Documents/Visual%20Studio/LL%20Odds%20JavaScript/null

What I expect:
file:///C:/Users/[my username]/OneDrive/Documents/Visual%20Studio/LL%20Odds%20JavaScript/AbilityOdds.html

edit: I've tried creating a new folder and putting EVERYTHING part of my project (including the file that I get the error with) inside of it. Still the same issue but when I put the singular file back into the first folder it seems to run fine. linking problem perhaps?

Comment: since when does HTML need linking, looks more like a browser cache issue. If your HTML has a form with `action` property you wont get much action unless you have a webserver that the HTML file was taken from

Comment: ChatGPT is no genius, it does only know what the creators has grabbed from the internet in put in the training data (a whole lot of Terra byte of text)

Comment: I was joking about chatgpt being smart, I know it has its limits. I’m just providing as much detail as possible that can help fix this issue